# Sublime Text 3: Moving tab from one panel (column) to another

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I use Sublime Text 3 in two column mode. I have several tabs open in each panel/column.
Current behavior:

[image]

(Upper part of diagram)
There are seven tabs open in the left panel. The current displayed tab is tab **2**. I move tab **7** over to the right panel.

(Lower part of diagram)
Result: The tab moves over to the right panel. It's displayed in the right panel. That's fine, whatever. On the **left panel**, though, tab **6** is now displayed instead of tab **2**.

Desired result: On the **left panel**, tab **2** should be displayed instead of tab **6**. Is there any setting to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting to do this as at build 3157. Someone wrote a plugin to handle this when closing tabs, maybe it could be adapted to work when moving tabs between groups also.
https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/455